# upload file in html form without <input>

Tags: html

Is it possible to include a file to be uploaded in an html "post" form with using ? I have an app that uses an html form for submitting bug reports and I want to include a log file from the users computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `input type="file"` for attaching file inside html form. As per my understanding you are trying to apply css `input type="file"` but it doesn't support much styling. If this is the case you can use `div` to wrap that `input`

```css
input[type="file"]{
  display: none;
  }
  
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: skyblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="file"/>
    FILE UPLOAD
</div>
```

Comment: This hides the file input nicely which is what I wanted. However html security prevents me from defining what file the input points to. Which makes sense. So this is a dead end for me. Thanks for the response tho.